# Error in a generated UserRepository upgradePassword() method

Tags: symfony

I've created a user class using **php bin/console make:user** and it automatically created a user repository that has this method and it contains an error. Is it anything serious? Could it potentially cause any problems when after some time it tries to rehash the password?

[image]

Nothing crashes when I launch the website. Seems to work just fine for now.

Comment: This is a temporary PhpStorm error. Just use "File->Invalidate Cache/Restart..." and it will go away.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!